# Obtener el Click del mouse al pulsar en la consola

Tags: c++

Estoy en un proyecto de escuela, necesito obtener el click al dar en la consola. 
Ahí donde pulse guardar las coordenadas `X, Y`
y meterlas en el `void GotoXY(int x, int y);` para que el programa siga imprimiendo en ese punto. Luego espere otro punto para empezar el ciclo de nuevo.

¿Existe algún método tipo `GetCursorPosition();`?

Aunque sea generado como el gotoxy.

Edito:

Tengo esto

```
BOOL WINAPI GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
  _In_  HANDLE                      hConsoleOutput,
  _Out_ PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo
);

int main(){
    int r = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int vuelta = 0;
    int sleep = 50;

    while(true){
        if(vuelta!=1){
            irA(i,j);
            r = rand()%11+1;
            pon_color(r);
            printf("Jose ");
            Sleep(100);
            //j = j+1; //esto mueve izquierda o derecha
            i = i+1; //esto mueve arriba o abajo
            if(i==25)
                vuelta = 1;

            irA(lpConsoleScreenBufferInfor.x, lpConsoleScreenBufferInfor.y);

    }
```

pero no me funciona, me da este error:

> nombre colores.cpp    [Warning] 'BOOL GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(HANDLE,
>   PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO)' redeclared without dllimport attribute:
>   previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]

Comment: y la parte de imprimir en el punto que tu le digas ya la tienes????

Comment: Agrega el código que estas ejecutando para que te puedan apoyar de una manera mas exacta

Comment: @ÁngelHernández no tengo hecho nada, apenas estoy empezando, solo necesito ese código para traer la posición del puntero en la consola.

Comment: @RobertoTellezIbarra en la etiqueta especifiqué que es dev-c++

Comment: @RobertoTellezIbarra entonces tal vez sea conveniente borrar los comentarios cuando los mismos carecen dw validez... los comentarios no deben formar parte de la historia de la pregunta. Dicho esto voy a borrar los mismos ya que esta conversaciones desvirtúa la pregunta

Comment: Estimado/a, los comentarios son parte importante, pero no más que su respuesta. Los comentarios SI forman parte de la historia de la pregunta, aunque en este caso gracias a su dedicación al mio, estos últimos no tengan relación con el objetivo original.

Answer (score 0):

La función es:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
  _In_  HANDLE                      hConsoleOutput,
  _Out_ PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo
);
```

Donde:

> `hConsoleOutput` es el manejador de la consola
>
> `lpConsoleScreenBufferInfor` contiene las coordenadas del cursor

`lpConsoleScreenBufferInfor.x` y `lpConsoleScreenBufferInfor.y` contienen las coordenas en x e y respectivamente.

Información más detallada en [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) (inglés) y un ejemplo en [Scrolling a Screen Buffer's Window](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrolling-a-screen-buffer-s-window) (inglés).

Answer (score 0):

> nombre colores.cpp [Warning] 'BOOL GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(HANDLE, PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]

La función se encuentra declarada en `windows.h`. Esta cabecera representa la puerta de entrada a la API de Windows y, a diferencia de la librería estándar, sus funciones se encuentran distribuídas en DLLs.

Para poder enlazar con una función que se encuentra en una DLL es necesario que, en la DLL, la función se marque como *exportable* (`__declspec(dllexport)`), mientras que en el cliente debe estar declarada como *importada* (`__declspec(dllimport)`).

El error se produce porque estás incluyendo la declaración de la función en tu programa directamente sin incluir la claúsula de importación. Entonces el compilador ve que la declaración de la función se solapa con una que ya existe en la DLL y te arroja un error porque no puedes tener dos funciones con el mismo nombre, mismo tipo de retorno y mismos argumentos. Además te está dando mucha información al indicarte que te una declaración se encuentra etiquetada con `dllimport`.

La solución es tan sencilla como borrar la declaración de la función en tu programa:

```
#include <windows.h>

// 
/* Esto fuera
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
 BOOL WINAPI GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
  _In_  HANDLE                      hConsoleOutput,
  _Out_ PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo
);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Hasta aqui */

int main(){
 // ...
```

Comment: sí, sí la tengo.

Comment: @JoseLuis Pues entonces borra la declaración de la función porque la función la estás declarando dos veces

Comment: lo tengo creo que todo.